# Why npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular --force/ return red function in Azure console

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, npm, deployment

I tried to deploy my angular-nodejs app on Azure. npm install won't do anything, I keep getting weird error message:

> function(t){if(void 0===t&&(t="legacy"),this._body instanceof b)return
>   this._body.toString();if(this._body instanceof
>   ArrayBuffer)switch(t){case"legacy":return
>   String.fromCharCode.apply(null,new
>   Uint16Array(this._body));case"iso-8859":return
>   String.fromCharCode.apply(null,new
>   Uint8Array(this._body));default:throw new Error("Invalid value for
>   encodingHint: "+t)}return null==this._body?"":"object"==typeof
>   this._body?JSON.stringify(this._body,null,2):this._body.toString()}

angular version:

```
Angular CLI: 7.3.9
Node: 10.14.1
OS: win32 ia32
Angular: <error>
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.13.9 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/build-angular   <error>
@angular-devkit/core            7.3.9 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics      7.3.9 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular             7.3.9 (cli-only)
@schematics/update              0.13.9 (cli-only)
rxjs                            6.3.3 (cli-only)
typescript                      3.2.4 (cli-only)
```

npm version:

```
6.9.0
```

node version:

```
v10.14.1
```

package.json:

```
{
"name": "veappfin",
"version": "0.0.0",
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng build && nodemon server.js",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "acorn": "^6.1.1",
    "ajv": "^6.10.0",
    "async": "^2.6.2",
    "azure-keyvault": "^3.0.4",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.4",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-validator": "^5.3.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.2",
    "jstransformer-babel": "^2.1.0",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "mssql": "^4.3.7",
    "multer": "^1.4.1",
    "npm": "^6.9.0",
    "npm-watch": "^0.5.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-azure-ad": "^4.0.0",
    "pug": "^2.0.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "tedious": "^2.7.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.9",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-pug": "^6.0.1",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "fsevents": "*",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
}
}
```